# How to play lottie starting at the end, playing backwards to the start of the animation in xamarin?

Tags: xamarin, lottie

Is there any option to play lottie starting at the end, playing backwards to the start of the animation in xamarin? From code behind in c#

```
<lottie:AnimationView x:Name="lottie" AutoPlay="False" Animation="heartreaction.json"  />
```

Clicked

```
private void super_Clicked(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        lottie.PlayAnimation();
        //Instead play it backwards
    }
```

Comment: "from the back" here means "starting at the end, playing backwards to the start of the animation"?

Comment: @ToolmakerSteve Yes it does

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you use SKLottieView, you could set `RepeatMode="Reverse"` to make it. You could add ***Skiasharp.Extended.UI.Forms*** Nuget first.

The following code is an example:

```
<skia:SKLottieView 
    HorizontalOptions="CenterAndExpand"
    VerticalOptions="CenterAndExpand"
    x:Name="myanimatedview"
    Source="dotnetbot.json"
    HeightRequest="300"
    WidthRequest="300"
    RepeatCount="-1"
    IsAnimationEnabled="True"
    RepeatMode="Reverse"/>
```

Or set it in code behind cs file:

```
myanimatedview.RepeatMode = SKLottieRepeatMode.Reverse;
```

Hope it works for you.

Comment: How would I specify the Assets path i.e. where to load the png images specified in the data.json file from?

Comment: Just put the json file in Resource/Raw folder. More info and sample code, you could refer to [Implement Lottie Animations in .NET MAUI Under 10 Minutes!](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=o5X5yXdWpuc)

Comment: Yes but the data.json file 's assets array is empty in that example and everywhere else!

Comment: Sorry I'm not quite understand what you want. (https://github.com/jfversluis/MauiLottieAnimationsSample/tree/main/MauiLottieAnimationsSample/Resources/Raw). You could see the json file in the path. Didn't the sample code work on your side?

Comment: Please check here as I have created an issue in the Github repo:

https://github.com/mono/SkiaSharp.Extended/issues/169